# Replacing existing View but MySQL says "Table doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table in my MySQL database, `compatibility_core_rules`, which essentially stores pairs of ids which represent compatibility between parts which have fields with those corresponding ids. Now, my aim is to get all possible compatibility pairs by following the transitivity of the pairs (e.g. so if the table has (1,2) and (2,4), then add the pair (1,4)). So, mathematically speaking, I'm trying to find the transitive closure of the `compatibility_core_rules` table.

E.g. if `compatibility_core_rules` contains (1,2), (2,4) and (4,9), then initially we can see that (1,2) and (2,4) gives a new pair (1,4). I then iterate over the updated pairs and find that (4,9) with the newly added (1,4) gives me (1,9). At this point, iterating again would add no more pairs.

So my approach is to create a view with the initial pairs from `compatibility_core_rules`, like so:

```
CREATE VIEW compatibility_core_rules_closure 
    AS
        SELECT  part_type_field_values_id_a, 
                part_type_field_values_id_b, 
                custom_builder_id
        FROM    compatibility_core_rules;
```

Then, in order to iteratively discover all pairs, I need to keep replacing that view with an updated version of itself that has additional pairs each time. However, I found MySQL doesn't like me referencing the view in its own definition, so I make a temporary view (with or replace, since this will be inside a loop):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW compatibility_core_rules_closure_temp 
    AS
        SELECT  part_type_field_values_id_a, 
                part_type_field_values_id_b, 
                custom_builder_id
        FROM    compatibility_core_rules_closure;
```

No problems here. I then reference this temporary view in the following CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement to update the `compatibility_core_rules_closure` view with one iteration's worth of additional pairs:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW compatibility_core_rules_closure 
    AS
        SELECT 
                    CASE WHEN ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_a = ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_a THEN ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_b
                         WHEN ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_a = ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_b THEN ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_b
                    END ccrA,
                    CASE WHEN ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_a = ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_a THEN ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_b
                         WHEN ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_a = ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_b THEN ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_a
                    END ccrB,
                    ccr1.custom_builder_id custom_builder_id
        FROM        compatibility_core_rules_closure_temp ccr1
        INNER JOIN  compatibility_core_rules_closure_temp ccr2 
            ON      (
                        ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_a = ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_a     OR
                        ccr1.part_type_field_values_id_a = ccr2.part_type_field_values_id_b
                    )
        GROUP BY    ccrA, 
                    ccrB
        HAVING      -- ccrA and ccrB are in fact not the same
                    ccrA != ccrB
                    -- ccrA and ccrB do not belong to the same part type
                    AND (
                            SELECT      ptf.part_type_id 
                            FROM        part_type_field_values ptfv 
                            INNER JOIN  part_type_fields ptf 
                                ON      ptfv.part_type_field_id = ptf.id 
                            WHERE       ptfv.id = ccrA 
                            LIMIT       1
                        ) !=
                        (
                            SELECT      ptf.part_type_id 
                            FROM        part_type_field_values ptfv 
                            INNER JOIN  part_type_fields ptf 
                                ON      ptfv.part_type_field_id = ptf.id 
                            WHERE       ptfv.id = ccrB 
                            LIMIT       1
                        )
```

Now this is where things go wrong. I get the following error:

```
#1146 - Table 'db509574872.compatibility_core_rules_closure' doesn't exist
```

I'm very confused by this error message. I literally just created the view/table only two statements ago. I'm sure the SELECT query itself is correct since if I try it by itself and it runs fine. If I change the first line to use `compatibility_core_rules_closure2` instead of `compatibility_core_rules_closure` then it runs fine (however, that's not much use since I need to be re-updating the same view again and again). I've looked into the SQL SECURITY clauses but have not had any success. Also been researching online but not getting anywhere.

Does anyone have any ideas what is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: MySQL doesn't do what you want to do.  It has very little (no?) support for hierarchical or recursive queries.  You can do what you want in a stored procedure by repeatedly iterating over the table.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I plan to do. The latter two queries above represent the main chunk of the contents of the procedure loop. However, I wanted to get the contents of the loop working first before I coded the procedure. Basically, what I describe above is me trying to "manually" running the statement that the loop would run. As I mention above, the big query performs a single iteration's worth of adding new pairs. However, I'm getting the error mentioned. Once I've figured out how to resolve that, it shouldn't too much trouble for me to code up the loop.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support sub-queries in views.

You'll have to separate them... ie. using another view containing the sub-query inside you main view.

Running the create statement for that view will render an error, not creating it, hence the doesn't exist error you're getting when querying it.

Comment: I don't think it's due to the subqueries, as I believe the subquery limitation only applies to them appearing in the FROM clause. The documentation doesn't explicitly say whether or not their permitted inside WHERE or HAVING as far as I can tell but I found that removing the subqueries in the big query above still left me with the same error.

Also, concerning your last statement, the view gets successfully created by the first query above (I can confirm I see it in PHPMyAdmin as well), so the view definitely exists at the time I run the third query.

Comment: Fair enough about the support.  About your last comment: trying to replace a working view with an erroneous one could of course delete the original one.